# How can find a radius from field of view of the panorama

Tags: three.js, panoramas, 360-panorama-viewer

I am using three.js for creating panoramic view . How one can find the radius and the area of the sphere  into which transforming .

Comment: `sphereGeometry.parameters.radius` will give the radius of the sphere.

Comment: can you tell me about radius unit ?